# Noisy channel coding: how to design a code for a discrete channel

Tags: information-theory

When determining the capacity of a discrete channel, we maximise mutual information, and in doing so find the optimal input distribution for that channel.

I know that the noisy-channel coding theorem does not give us a practical scheme to design a code that achieves a communication rate equal to the capacity of the channel; it only tells us that it is possible to do so. However, I am wondering if there is any intuition, or any general set of techniques, that one might use to design a code for a channel, given the optimal input distribution?

For example, let's say we have a source with $p_0=0.5$ and $p_1=0.5$ and we wish to transmit strings from that source through a Z-channel with optimal input distribution $p_0^{\star} = 0.4$ and $p_1^{\star} = 0.6$. What kinds of coding techniques could we apply (if any) to change the distribution of the source into the optimal input distribution for the channel?

Comment: The proof of the noisy channel coding theorem does tell us how to design a code: choose it at random.

Comment: But no practical encoder/decoder could work in this way? I'll update my question.

Comment: There are entire disciplines dealing with constructing efficiently decodable error-correcting codes, namely information theory and coding theory.

Comment: When beginning to study a field, it is useful to have some intuition about how one might go about implementing the goals of that field. It is intuition that this question is asking for, in good faith.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is difficult to compress over seven decades of research into a few intuitions.